# How to detect stale data in search result with paging?

Tags: caching, search, language-agnostic

Let's say we have a REST API for search:
/items?querystring=foo&pagesize=20&page=3

As the search results are fetched page after page, the search total results might change and items of each page might vary while browsing through pages.

What kind of approaches there are to detect changes in data? Total number of result is one indication but not really fool proof.

Answer (score 1):

usually there is none detection. when you enter a page, new request is done (REST) and most recent data for that page are displayed. google says '*about* x results in total'. if you really insist on having the counter fixed, you have to stop calling your service 'a rest', take a snapshot from the first search and display disabled entries when user browse pages